# Надо интегрировать сайт на wordpress в ВК сервисы

Tags: wordpress, node.js, vkontakte-api

Все подключается. На компьютере все открывается ВК. А на телефоне бесконечная загрузка. Как оказалось причина в отсутствии VKconnect. Вопрос: как интегрировать VKconnect на сайт на WordPress.

Comment: Что подключается? Что открывается?

Comment: Для создания сервисов ВК используется платформа VK apps. Она требует, чтобы на сервис была подключена библиотека VKconnect. Только вот это подключаетс к node.js сервису. А у меня сайт на WordPress. Вопрос: как можно подключить чтобы все работало.